# creating text based editor plugins for eclipse wizard page

Tags: swt, eclipse-plugin

I have developed an eclipse plugin project. I need a text editor that can save, copy, paste, search. This text editor must be inserted in the wizard pages which are developed using swt.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

In a plug-in you can use the JFace `org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewer`.

You will to provide save and search. `TextViewer` does support the interface required by the Eclipse `org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.FindReplaceDialog`.

If you really only want SWT code then use `org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText`